# BlackBerry Native - using navigationpane to change between pages

Tags: qml, blackberry-10

I am develop an application for blackberry which using navigation pane to change between page. Below are some of the code i wrote.

trainee_list.qml

```
import bb.cascades 1.0

NavigationPane {
id: navigationPane
onPopTransitionEnded: page.destroy()
Page {
    content: Container {
        background: Color.create("#4adfe1c1")
        // Create a ListView that uses an XML data model
        ListView {...
            listItemComponents: [...]
            onTriggered: {...}
            attachedObjects: [
                ComponentDefinition {
                    id: nextpage
                    source: "trainee_info.qml"
                }]}}}}
```

below are the second page.

trainee_info.qml

```
import bb.cascades 1.0

Page {
Container {
    layout: AbsoluteLayout {}

    background: Color.create("#4adfe1c1")
    ImageView {
        imageSource: "profile.png"
        layoutProperties: AbsoluteLayoutProperties {
            positionX: 120
            positionY: 150
        }
        scaleX: 1.7
        scaleY: 2
    }}}
```

The problem now is when i add "navigationpane" to the second page (trainee_info.qml) to navigate to third page, i can no longer navigate from first page (trainee_list.qml) to the second page (trainee_info.qml).

```
NavigationPane {
...secondpage...
}
```

is there alternative for navigating between screen other than navigatingpane?

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need NavigationPane on your second page. Use the one from the first one. 
*navigationPane* is accessible from the second page as well